# How to add a new property to Jekylls posts?

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I want to do something like:

```
{% for post in site.posts %}
  {% assign post.myProprty = "something" %}
{% endfor %}
```

But it doesn't work. Is that another way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I could make it happen using a plugin.

plugin code:

```
module Jekyll
  module AddProp
    def addProp(input, key, value)
      input[key] = value
      return input
    end
  end
end

Liquid::Template.register_filter(Jekyll::AddProp)
```

Usage:

```
{% for post in site.posts %}
  {% assign post = post | addProp: "myProprty", "something" %}
{% endfor %}
```

Plugin [GitHub repository](https://github.com/ferrriii/JekylPlugins#filter-to-add-property-to-hash-addproprb)